# error adding xml-style sheet to an SVG object inside javascript

Tags: css, svg

I get an error when adding this line of code to my javascript file,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

```
var data = "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/css' href='css/main.css' ?>"+
        "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='800' height='800'>"+
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
         "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>"+$("#mainbody").html() 
             + "</div></foreignObject></svg>";
```

the problem disaaperas when I remove this part:

```
"<?xml-stylesheet type='text/css' href='css/main.css' ?>"
```

moreever I have the same line in another file, but no problems at all

what could be the problem?

Comment: Does this error occur when you define the string or when you use it? If it's when you use it then you haven't shown us that code.

Comment: it shows when I define that string

Comment: And if you break it up e.g. data = "<" + "?xml-st.... css' ?" + ">" +

Comment: but still didn't applay the style sheet to the SVG object

Comment: Ummm, the answer below explains why the stylesheet was not applied to the SVG object. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP error. You need to escape the `<?` or `?>` sequences, which of course have a special meaning to PHP.

HOWEVER, even after you fix that and make PHP happy, what you are trying to do will not work. When you try to set the "html" property of some DOM node to this `data` variable you're defining, you'll get a different error saying the DOM string is malformed (or, possibly, the `<?xml-stylesheet?>` pseudo-instruction will be ignored). That's because `xml-stylesheet` is something that comes at the beginning of an **XML document**, not within a textual DOM fragment of the sort that can be assigned to an element's `html` property. It takes takes effect when an SVG **document** is displayed, not on an SVG fragment within an HTML page.

What are you trying to accomplish here? The `main.css` file contains css declarations that are particular just to that fragment of SVG? Why not just include the CSS file in the HEAD of the HTML file?

Another possible solution is to externalize the SVG as a separate file, and include that using an IMG element or something--in that case the `<?xml-stylesheet?>` pseudo-instruction will work just fine. But that will not allow you to do what you seem to be trying to do with the `$("#mainbody")` thing--which is...what? To somehow wrap the HTML in SVG? Why?